# by ref argument type mismatch VB 6.0

Tags: oracle, vb6

I have a trouble debugging this program wherein byref argument type mismatch always appear in this module. from the part Initialize, S2_GetTaskIDs, s2_GetAllTasks are fine but when it moves to s2_Sort the problem appears. variables dCnt,tCnt,sCnt,wCnt are all integers.

```vb
'for checking of worker on upper level
Dim dicDay As New Dictionary
Dim dicShift As New Dictionary


Public Sub S2_CreateReport()

    Initialize '[open connection to oracle]
    S2_GetTaskIDs 'get the distinct task ids

    S2_GetAllTasks '[get the bulk of tasks for the project, between the days, transfer to s2]

    S2_Sort 'sort the Datarecord

    CloseAll '[close connection to oracle]

    S2_ComputeMode

    S2_PlanReport

    S2_PrintReport

    S2_ForecastReport

End Sub

Private Sub S2_GetTaskIDs()

    Dim rstTask As ADODB.Recordset

    strQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT TASK_ID, DESCRIPTION FROM PROD_DB WHERE PROJECT_ID = '" & inpProject & "' ORDER BY TASK_ID"

    Set rstTask = AdoConn.Execute(strQuery)
    tCnt = 0
    ReDim TaskID(tCnt)
    rstTask.MoveFirst

    Do While Not rstTask.EOF
        tCnt = tCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve TaskID(tCnt)

        TaskID(tCnt).TaskID = rstTask.Fields("TASK_ID").Value
        TaskID(tCnt).TaskName = rstTask.Fields("DESCRIPTION").Value

        rstTask.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set rstTask = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub S2_GetAllTasks()


    'Dim pQ As String
    Dim rstTask As ADODB.Recordset

    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM PROD_DB WHERE"

    'get pcodes
    'For pCnt = 1 To UBound(PCode())
    '    If pQ = "" Then
    '        pQ = " (PROJECT_ID LIKE '" & PCode(pCnt) & "%'"
    '    Else
    '        pQ = pQ & " OR PROJECT_ID LIKE '" & PCode(pCnt) & "%'"
    '    End If
    'Next pCnt

    'pQ = pQ & ")"

    'select * from element_history where (eprocstart>= to_timestamp('Aug-01-2010 06',
    'MON-DD-YYYY HH24') And (eprocend < (to_timestamp('Aug-05-2010 23',
    'MON-DD-YYYY HH24') + interval '6' hour)))
    strQuery = strQuery & _
                " (PROJECT_ID LIKE '" & inpProject & "')" & _
                " AND (START_TIME >= to_timestamp('" & inpDateS & " 06', 'MON-DD-YYYY HH24')" & _
                " AND (END_TIME < (to_timestamp('" & inpDateE & " 23', 'MON-DD-YYYY HH24') + interval '6' hour)))" & _
                "ORDER BY START_TIME, TASK_ID"

    Set rstTask = AdoConn.Execute(strQuery)
    tCnt = 0
    'ReDim TaskID(tCnt)
    If Not (rstTask.EOF And rstTask.BOF) Then
        rstTask.MoveFirst

        Do While Not rstTask.EOF
            'For dCnt = 1 To UBound(S2.Day())
                'if the record is within the day
            '    If CDate(rstTask.Fields("START_TIME").Value) = CDate(S2.Day(dCnt)) Then

                    ReDim Preserve DataRecord(tCnt)
                    DataRecord(tCnt).TaskID = rstTask.Fields("TASK_ID").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).StartTime = rstTask.Fields("START_TIME").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).EndTime = rstTask.Fields("END_TIME").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).Description = rstTask.Fields("DESCRIPTION").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).ProjectID = rstTask.Fields("PROJECT_ID").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).DomainID = rstTask.Fields("DOMAIN_ID").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).RoleID = rstTask.Fields("ROLE_ID").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).NextTask = rstTask.Fields("NEXT_TASK").Value
                    '***DataRecord(tCnt).Cost = rstTask.Fields("COST").Value

                    If rstTask.Fields("COST").Value = Null Then
                    DataRecord(tCnt).Cost = ""
                    End If
                    If rstTask.Fields("MEASUREMENT_UNIT").Value = Null Then
                    DataRecord(tCnt).MeasurementUnit = ""
                    End If

                    '***DataRecord(tCnt).MeasurementUnit = rstTask.Fields("MEASUREMENT_UNIT").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).duration = rstTask.Fields("TOTAL_MINUTES_WORKED").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).CompletedUnit = rstTask.Fields("COMPLETED_UNITS").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).TotalWaitTime = rstTask.Fields("TOTAL_WAITING_TIME").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).CompletedWork = rstTask.Fields("COMPLETED_WORK").Value
                    '***DataRecord(tCnt).ErrorUnit = rstTask.Fields("ERROR_UNITS").Value

                    If rstTask.Fields("ERROR_UNITS").Value = Null Then
                    DataRecord(tCnt).ErrorUnit = ""
                    End If

                    If IsNull(rstTask.Fields("RESOURCE_NAME").Value) Then
                        DataRecord(tCnt).ResourceName = ""
                    Else
                        DataRecord(tCnt).ResourceName = rstTask.Fields("RESOURCE_NAME").Value
                    End If
                    DataRecord(tCnt).MinWaitTime = rstTask.Fields("MIN_WAIT_TIME").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).MaxWaitTime = rstTask.Fields("MAX_WAIT_TIME").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).AveWaitTime = rstTask.Fields("AVE_WAIT_TIME").Value
                    If IsNull(rstTask.Fields("MODE_WAIT_TIME").Value) Then
                        DataRecord(tCnt).ModeWaitTime = ""
                    Else
                        DataRecord(tCnt).ModeWaitTime = rstTask.Fields("MODE_WAIT_TIME").Value
                    End If
                    DataRecord(tCnt).MinProcTime = rstTask.Fields("MIN_PROC_TIME").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).MaxProcTime = rstTask.Fields("MAX_PROC_TIME").Value
                    DataRecord(tCnt).AveProcTime = rstTask.Fields("AVE_PROC_TIME").Value
                    If IsNull(rstTask.Fields("MODE_PROC_TIME").Value) Then
                        DataRecord(tCnt).ModeProcTime = ""
                    Else
                        DataRecord(tCnt).ModeProcTime = rstTask.Fields("MODE_PROC_TIME").Value
                    End If
'                    DataRecord(tCnt).ModeProcTime = rstTask.Fields("MODE_PROC_TIME").Value
                    rstTask.MoveNext
                    tCnt = tCnt + 1
            '    End If
            'Next dCnt
        Loop
    End If
    Set rstTask = Nothing

End Sub
Public Sub S2_Sort()

    'loop day
    For dCnt = 1 To UBound(S2.Day())
        ReDim S2.Day(dCnt).tList(0)

        'loop shift
        For tCnt = 1 To UBound(TaskID())
            ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt)
            ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(0)
            'dicShift.RemoveAll

            'loop task
            For sCnt = 1 To UBound(Shift())
                ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt)
                ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(0)

                'query with paramaters for project, datetime, and taskid
                 strQuery = "SELECT * FROM PROD_DB WHERE PROJECT_ID = '" & inpProject & "'" & _
                        " AND " & GetTimestamp(S2.Day(dCnt).DayVal, Shift(sCnt).NextDay, True, Shift(sCnt).StartHour, _
                        Shift(sCnt).HourLen) & _
                        " AND TASK_ID = '" & TaskID(tCnt).TaskID & "'" & _
                        " ORDER BY START_TIME, TASK_ID"
                Set rstInfo = AdoConn.Execute(strQuery)

                If Not (rstInfo.EOF And rstInfo.BOF) Then
                    rstInfo.MoveFirst
                    wCnt = 0
                    Do Until rstInfo.EOF
                        wCnt = wCnt + 1
                        ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(wCnt)
                        'save the records to a arraylist datarecord
                        Call SetDataRecord(rstInfo, wCnt)

                        'then compute, get the work time number and list it on stLIst
                        S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val = S2_Compute(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(wCnt), S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val)
                        S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val = S2_Compute(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(wCnt), S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val)
                        'S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).MstUnit = DataRecord(X).MeasurementUnit
                        'S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Cost = DataRecord(X).Cost
                        S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).ResourceName = S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).ResourceName + S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(wCnt).ResourceName
                        S2.Day(dCnt).Val = S2_Compute(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(wCnt), S2.Day(dCnt).Val)

                        rstInfo.MoveNext
                    Loop
                End If
                Set rstInfo = Nothing
            Next sCnt 'Next Shift
        Next tCnt 'Next Task
    Next dCnt 'Next Day
End Sub

Private Function setStandard(Rec As Double) 'udt_DTSS_VAL
    Dim m As Integer

    'Rec.duration / Rec.CompletedWork
    If inpOpt = "Duration" Then
        stdDuration = Rec.duration + stdDuration
        stdWork = stdWork + Rec.CompletedWork
    ElseIf inpOpt = "Min Proc Time" Then
        m = Rec.MinProcTime / Rec.CompletedWork
        'minimum
        If stdMinTime = 0 Then
            stdMinTime = m
        Else
            If m < stdMinTime Then
                stdMinTime = m
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf inpOpt = "Max Proc Time" Then
        m = Rec.MaxProcTime / Rec.CompletedWork
        'max
        If stdMaxTime = 0 Then
            stdMaxTime = m
        Else
            If m > stdMaxTime Then
                stdMaxTime = m
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf inpOpt = "Ave Proc Time" Then
        m = Rec.AveProcTime / Rec.CompletedWork
        'average
        'if no contents yet, assign to the datarecord
        If stdAveTime = 0 Then
            stdAveTime = m
        Else
            stdAveTime = (m + stdAveTime) / 2
        End If
    ElseIf inpOpt = "Mode Proc Time" Then
        'store mode in array of string
        'count its frequency
        'null muna
        'm = False
        'i = 0
        'ReDim Preserve Rec.ModeProcTimeVal(0)
        'ReDim Preserve Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(0)
        'If Rec.ModeProcTimeVal(0) = "" Then
        '    Rec.ModeProcTimeVal(0) = DataRecord(x).ModeProcTime
        '    Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(0) = 1
        'Else
        '    Do While i < UBound(Rec.ModeProcTimeVal()) And m = False
        '        If Rec.ModeProcTimeVal(i) = DataRecord(x).ModeProcTime Then
        '            Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(i) = Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(i) + 1
        '            m = True
        '        End If
        '        i = i + 1
        '    Loop
        '    If m = False Then
        '        Rec.ModeProcTimeVal(i) = DataRecord(x).ModeProcTime
        '        Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(i) = Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(i) + 1
        '    End If
        'End If
    End If

End Function

Private Function S2_Compute(X As Integer, Rec As udt_DTSS_VAL) As udt_DTSS_VAL
    Dim m As Boolean

    'add
    Rec.duration = (Rec.duration + DataRecord(X).duration)
    Rec.CompletedWork = (Rec.CompletedWork + DataRecord(X).CompletedWork)
    Rec.ErrorUnits = (Rec.ErrorUnits + DataRecord(X).ErrorUnit)
    Rec.TotalWaitTime = (Rec.TotalWaitTime + DataRecord(X).TotalWaitTime)
    Rec.CompletedUnit = (Rec.CompletedUnit + DataRecord(X).CompletedUnit)


    'average
    'if no contents yet, assign to the datarecord
    If Rec.AveProcTime = 0 Then
        Rec.AveProcTime = DataRecord(X).AveProcTime
'        stdAveTime = DataRecord(x).AveProcTime
    Else
        Rec.AveProcTime = (Rec.AveProcTime + DataRecord(X).AveProcTime) / 2
'        stdAveTime = (stdAveTime + DataRecord(x).AveProcTime) / 2
    End If

    If Rec.AveWaitTime = 0 Then
        Rec.AveWaitTime = DataRecord(X).AveWaitTime
    Else
        Rec.AveWaitTime = (Rec.AveWaitTime + DataRecord(X).AveWaitTime) / 2
    End If

    'minimum
    If Rec.MinProcTime = 0 Then
        Rec.MinProcTime = DataRecord(X).MinProcTime
        'stdMinTime = DataRecord(x).MinProcTime
    Else
        If DataRecord(X).MinProcTime < Rec.MinProcTime Then
            Rec.MinProcTime = DataRecord(X).MinProcTime
        End If
        'If DataRecord(x).MinProcTime < stdMinTime Then
        '    stdMinTime = DataRecord(x).MinProcTime
        'End If
    End If

    If Rec.MinWaitTime = 0 Then
        Rec.MinWaitTime = DataRecord(X).MinWaitTime
    Else
        If DataRecord(X).MinWaitTime < Rec.MinWaitTime Then
            Rec.MinWaitTime = DataRecord(X).MinWaitTime
        End If
    End If

    'max
    If Rec.MaxProcTime = 0 Then
        Rec.MaxProcTime = DataRecord(X).MaxProcTime
    Else
        If DataRecord(X).MaxProcTime > Rec.MaxProcTime Then
            Rec.MaxProcTime = DataRecord(X).MaxProcTime
        End If
    End If

    If Rec.MaxWaitTime = 0 Then
        Rec.MaxWaitTime = DataRecord(X).MaxWaitTime
    Else
        If DataRecord(X).MaxWaitTime < Rec.MaxWaitTime Then
            Rec.MaxWaitTime = DataRecord(X).MaxWaitTime
        End If
    End If

    'StartTime
    If Rec.StartTime = "" Then
        Rec.StartTime = DataRecord(X).StartTime
    Else
        If FormatDateTime(DataRecord(X).StartTime) < FormatDateTime(Rec.StartTime) Then
            Rec.StartTime = DataRecord(X).StartTime
        End If
    End If

    'EndTime
    If Rec.EndTime = "" Then
        Rec.EndTime = DataRecord(X).EndTime
    Else
        If FormatDateTime(DataRecord(X).EndTime) > FormatDateTime(Rec.EndTime) Then
            Rec.EndTime = DataRecord(X).EndTime
        End If
    End If

    'store mode in array of string
    'count its frequency
    m = False
    i = 0
    ReDim Preserve Rec.ModeProcTimeVal(0)
    ReDim Preserve Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(0)
    If Rec.ModeProcTimeVal(0) = "" Then
        Rec.ModeProcTimeVal(0) = DataRecord(X).ModeProcTime
        Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(0) = 1
    Else
        Do While i < UBound(Rec.ModeProcTimeVal()) And m = False
            If Rec.ModeProcTimeVal(i) = DataRecord(X).ModeProcTime Then
                Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(i) = Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(i) + 1
                m = True
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        If m = False Then
            Rec.ModeProcTimeVal(i) = DataRecord(X).ModeProcTime
            Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(i) = Rec.ModeProcTimeCount(i) + 1
        End If
    End If

    'mode wait
    m = False
    i = 0
    ReDim Preserve Rec.ModeWaitTimeVal(0)
    ReDim Preserve Rec.ModeWaitTimeCount(0)
    If Rec.ModeWaitTimeVal(0) = "" Then
        Rec.ModeWaitTimeVal(0) = DataRecord(X).ModeWaitTime
        Rec.ModeWaitTimeCount(0) = 1
    Else
        Do While i < UBound(Rec.ModeWaitTimeVal()) And m = False
            If Rec.ModeWaitTimeVal(i) = DataRecord(X).ModeWaitTime Then
                Rec.ModeWaitTimeCount(i) = Rec.ModeWaitTimeCount(i) + 1
                m = True
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        If m = False Then
            Rec.ModeWaitTimeVal(i) = DataRecord(X).ModeWaitTime
            Rec.ModeWaitTimeCount(i) = Rec.ModeWaitTimeCount(i) + 1
        End If
    End If

    'generated
    Rec.Generated = True

    'ResourceName
    'Rec.ResourceName = DataRecord(x).ResourceName

    S2_Compute = Rec
End Function

Private Sub S2_ComputeMode()

    For dCnt = 1 To UBound(S2.Day())

        Debug.Print "Mode " & dCnt
        Dim mdP As Integer, mdW As Integer

        mdP = GetMax(S2.Day(dCnt).Val.ModeProcTimeCount())
        mdW = GetMax(S2.Day(dCnt).Val.ModeWaitTimeCount())

        ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).Val.ModeProcTimeVal(mdP)
        ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).Val.ModeWaitTimeVal(mdW)

        S2.Day(dCnt).Val.ModeProcTime = S2.Day(dCnt).Val.ModeProcTimeVal(mdP)
        S2.Day(dCnt).Val.ModeWaitTime = S2.Day(dCnt).Val.ModeWaitTimeVal(mdW)

        For tCnt = 1 To UBound(S2.Day(dCnt).tList())

            Debug.Print "Mode " & dCnt & "-" & TaskID(tCnt).TaskID

            'get mode of task(day)
            'wList() = S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val.ModeProcTimeCount()
            Dim mP As Integer, mW As Integer

            mP = GetMax(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val.ModeProcTimeCount())
            mW = GetMax(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val.ModeWaitTimeCount())

            ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val.ModeProcTimeVal(mP)
            ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val.ModeWaitTimeVal(mW)

            S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val.ModeProcTime = S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val.ModeProcTimeVal(mP)
            S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val.ModeWaitTime = S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val.ModeWaitTimeVal(mW)
            'S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val.ModeDuration = Val(GetLevelMode(wList(), False))

            For sCnt = 1 To UBound(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList())

                Debug.Print "Mode " & dCnt & "-" & TaskID(tCnt).TaskID & "-" & sCnt
                Dim msP As Integer, msW As Integer
                'getmode of task(shift)
                msP = GetMax(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val.ModeProcTimeCount())
                msW = GetMax(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val.ModeWaitTimeCount())

                ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val.ModeProcTimeVal(msP)
                ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val.ModeWaitTimeVal(msW)

                S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val.ModeProcTime = S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val.ModeProcTimeVal(msP)
                S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val.ModeWaitTime = S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val.ModeWaitTimeVal(msW)
                'wList() = S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).wList()
                'S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val.ModeEid = Val(GetLevelMode(wList(), True))
                'S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val.ModeDuration = Val(GetLevelMode(wList(), False))

            Next sCnt 'Next Task(Shift)
        Next tCnt 'Next Task(Day)
    Next dCnt 'Next Day

End Sub

Private Function GetMax(List() As Integer) As Integer
    'Val (Math.Max(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val.ModeProcTimeCount))
    Dim mx As Integer, index As Integer
    ReDim Preserve List(0)
    mx = List(0)
    index = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(List())
        If (mx < List(i)) Then
            mx = List(i)
            index = i
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print index
    GetMax = index
End Function

Public Function GetTimestamp(vDate As String, vHour As String, vHourLen As String, vNextDay As Boolean, DateRecord As udtRecord) As Boolean

    Dim sq As Boolean
    Dim sDate As String, sss As String
    Dim st As Date, et As Date, est As Date, eet As Date
    'Dim i As Integer
    st = FormatDateTime(DateRecord.StartTime)
    et = FormatDateTime(DateRecord.EndTime)

    est = FormatDateTime((vDate + " " + vHour + ":00:00"))
    'If vNextDay = True Then
    '    sDate = DateAdd("d", 1, CDate(vDate))
    'Else
    '    sDate = CDate(vDate)
    'End If
    'sss = (CInt(vHour) + CInt(vHourLen))
    eet = FormatDateTime(DateAdd("h", vHourLen, est))


    sq = (et > est) And (et <= eet)

    'sQ = " END_TIME >= to_timestamp('" & sDate & "','MON-DD-YYYY HH24')" & _
        " AND END_TIME < (to_timestamp('" & sDate & "','MON-DD-YYYY HH24') " & _
            " + interval '" & vHourLen & "' hour)"

    'sQ = " h.eprocend >= to_timestamp('" & sDate & " " & Format(vHour, "00") & "','MON-DD-YYYY HH24')" & _
        " AND h.eprocend < (to_timestamp('" & sDate & " " & Format(vHour, "00") & "','MON-DD-YYYY HH24') " & _
            " + interval '" & vHourLen & "' hour)"
    GetTimestamp = sq

    ''SELECT *  FROM PROD_DB WHERE (TASK_ID like 'W14') AND (END_TIME>= to_timestamp('Dec-07-2011 06','MON-DD-YYYY HH24') AND END_TIME < (to_timestamp('Dec-07-2011 06','MON-DD-YYYY HH24')  + interval '4' hour))
End Function
```

Comment: This is really long and hard to read... nobody here in SO will even try. Can you show us only a small part of the code - the part that causes the problem ? and maybe some explanations ?

Comment: If you debug the code, exactly what line throws the error?

Comment: form the S2_Sort part where in 'query with paramaters for project, datetime, and taskid part of it. when I run it and show the byref argument error the NextDay from the strQuery is highlighted. I've been working for about a week now but still cant find a solution. hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All parameters in VB6 are called `ByRef` by default. To call `ByVal` is necessary to write it explicitly.

> If you pass a parameter to a function or sub procedure by reference,
>   the type of the actual parameter passed and the corresponding function
>   argument must match. Otherwise, you will get a "ByRef argument type
>   mismatch" error.

[How to Avoid the "ByRef Argument Type Mismatch" Error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138535/en-us?fr=1)

Your code is too long to find what is going on without knowing the exact line of exception.
Just a tip is that the line:

```
Call SetDataRecord(rstInfo, wCnt)
```

has exchanged parameters.

Comment: what can you further explain what can be the possible solution for it? im really a noob.

Comment: When I am right try Call SetDataRecord(wCnt, rstInfo). If it doesn't work try to identify exact line causing exception. Toggle break on all errors can be useful.